# Android studio download error(Request failed with status code 416)

Tags: android

While installing Android Studio(Sources for android 29) I am getting the above error. What could be the reason?
[image]

Thanks,

Comment: Try after sometime , may be server experiencing issue. i have same error in the morning, but after sometime its started working.

Answer (score 1):

Go to this location-

> C:\Users\gauta\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk.downloadIntermediates

In place of *gauta write your username

Then delete all the files in **downloadIntermediates** and again download the package from `sdk` manager..

this worked for me `(Error code-416)`